# Cannot paste into ACE editor from Android or iOS devices

Tags: javascript, android, ios, ace-editor

When I load an ACE editor editor, I am unable to paste from an Android device from the default browser (??? - AT&T HTC One), Chrome, or Firefox, with Android 4.1.2.  I confirmed the same behavior on Android 4.4, and also on an iPhone 4S.

See an example here:  http://jsfiddle.net/anthonyserious/mhu56k6h/1/.  If you try to paste into the editor, the usual "select/copy/paste" menu flickers for a second and then disappears.  This is with a trivial editor initialized:

```
var editor = ace.edit("editor");
editor.getSession().setMode("ace/mode/javascript");
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  Maybe there is an ACE editor property that can be set?

Thanks.

Comment: Ugh, I'm reading https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/37 and realizing that there's a long history of mobile support for ACE.

Comment: I had the same issue